# quiero eliminar datos de mi base de datos de firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

quiero realizar la eliminacion de los datos subidos a firebase los cuales puedo, visualizar, ingresar, pero, no puedo eliminar, hago el metodo, para dicha funcion,pero, no puedo eliminar los datos, ingresados.

```
export class UsuariosComponent {
  constructor(
    private fire: EnvironmentsService,
    private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private getUser: EnvironmentsService
  ) {}

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;

  listUser: usuario[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUser.getUser().subscribe((user) => {
      this.listUser = user;
      console.log(this.listUser);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.listUser);
    });
  }
  dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<any>;
```

como ven los metodos, get y add me funcionan normalmente, pero, delte no funciona.

```
  addUser(user: usuario) {
    const userReg = collection(this.firestore, 'crud');
    return addDoc(userReg, user);
  }

  getUser(): Observable<any[]> {
    const userReg = collection(this.firestore, 'crud');

    return collectionData(userReg, { idField: 'id' }) as Observable<any[]>;
  }

  deleteUser(user: usuario) {
    const docReg = doc(this.firestore, `crud${user.id}`);

    return deleteDoc(docReg);
  }

  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'Username',
    'Name',
    'Lastname',
    'Sex',
    'Action',
  ];
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
  applyFilter(event: Event): void {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

  async eliminarUsuario(user: any) {
    const deleteId = await this.fire.deleteUser(user);
    this._snackBar.open('el usuario ya fue eliminado', '', {
      duration: 3000,
      horizontalPosition: 'center',
      verticalPosition: 'top',
    });
  }
}
```

se ejecuta todo, el metodo, pero, el usuario no se elimina.yo creo que el problema es que no recibe el id del elemento a eliminar, lo revise con console.log(y cuando quiero saber que returna, me sale uncouhgt promise.)

Comment: Cuando trabajas con Promesas y `async / await` deberías usar un bloque `try ... catch` de esa forma podrás ver (depurar) el posible error si la Promesa es rechazada. Por otro lado, en tu función `eliminarUsuario` recibes una variable llamada `user` y la denotas como `any`. Porqué? No sabes de antemano el tipo de dato que representa `user`? No uses `any`, usa el tipo de dato adecuado. En general, debes evitar siempre el uso de `any`. Saludos

Comment: si lo intente pero, no se por que no me permitia, no lo puse any, la verdad, por que estoy estudiando todavia, y fue el unico modo en que me permitia usar la app, igualmente en este momento, estoy peliando por que instale unas dependecias y me rompieron la pagina, las elimine y me siguen sin dejar usar la pag